# unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.browser-wasm

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, webassembly

I am getting an "unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.browser-wasm" error when trying to Build an AspNetCore 5.0.0 Blazor Wasm app using VS Community 2019 v16.8.3.  I haven't tried to Build this app since early December, but it worked then. I get the same error when I try to Build older backup copies of the app too.

I have in recent days created a new AspNetCore 3.2.1 Blazor Wasm app using the same VS.  It Builds and runs successfully.

A search for this error indicates this package is not meant for direct consumption and I can't find anything else that's helpful.

Any idea how to get out of this?

Comment: Maybe something is off with your nuget feed setup in general and perhaps other packages work because you have them in the local nuget cache but not this one. Maybe you have a nuget.config file that does not have nuget.org as a feed, or a networking issue.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I'm afraid I don't understand well enough.  I searched my VS project for a nuget.config file, but didn't find one.  Perhaps it is not in the project itself.  I also looked through the Package Manager Settings, but didn't see anything I could change that made a difference.  The Package Sources only shows "MS VS Offline Packages", which could connect to your thoughts.  But I don't know what to add or how to add it.

Comment: I remembered this morning that I upgraded VS to 16.8.3 a couple of weeks ago, perhaps since the last time I was able to successfully Build.  I am looking for a way to revert back to 16.8.2, which I think was the previous version I used.

Comment: You don't have the default Nuget.org source so you can't restore packages. You need to add it, not downgrade vs

Comment: Can't begin to imagine how I lost the default Nuget.org source in the NuGet Manager's Package Sources, but I added it and can now Build.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you knew how you lost it, you would probably have not lost or in the first place :) glad to see you up and running

Answer (score 0):

The solution @rdmptn wrote as a comment worked for me. After upgrading VS I needed to add nuget.org to my list of Package Sources in the NuGet Package Manager options then rebuild the solution.